# Google Form Prefilled shortcut not working

Tags: forms, url

With the recent "upgrade" to Google Forms saving data, prefilled URLs no longer seem to work.
Steps to recreate problem:

1. create a Google Form
2. Create a prefilled URL for some of the fields
3. Open the form on an Android phone
4. Create a shortcut on the phone's homescreen from the "Save to homescreen" option on the form's menu
5. Open the form from the shortcut and submit a response
6. Open the form again from the shortcut -- the form will no longer have prefilled values.

Anyone have a workaround for this? I have a fairly large form that I use to track some tasks with some standard response values. This worked perfectly before the "upgrade" but now is useless saved as a shortcut. I can still use the prefilled URL from an email or another rich text object available on the phone, but needing to open additional documents is frustrating after getting used to the convenience of one click of an icon for years.

Comment: please share with us your workout, code snippets, error logs, or any useful information to help answer your question.

Comment: @novonimo, I'm not sure there is anything to add. I detailed the steps to recreate the issue. With Google Forms, there is no code snippets or error logs. If you are unfamiliar with Google Forms and using "prefilled" URLs with them, I thank you for following-up but doubt I can provide you with anything further to better understand this issue.

Answer (score 0):

I've had the same issue. Not quite as convenient but I've posted the URL of the prefilled link on a Google note so its still one click away with Google note on the home screen.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue.  The fix that worked for me was to remove the "autosave" option in the forms settings.

**Settings -> Presentation -> Disable auto-save for all respondents**